# I need to know if my variable contains a specific word

Tags: ios, swift

I need to know if the variable "act" contains a specific string and print true or false.

I tried multiple times to use "contains" function but it's like it's not built in.

It's like "contains" doesn't exists when I put it in the func "parseJson" and if I put it out of that I get that "act" doesn't exist.

Beginner here!

What I tried :

```
if act.contains("string") {
                     print("exists")
                }
```

And

```
if let str = act?.url!.absoluteString , str.contains("allo@allo.com")
                {
                print("matches")
                } else {
                print("doesnt match")
                }
```

I get this kind of error : Value of type 'Activity' has no member 'contains'

My code:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

protocol HomeModelDelegate
{
    func itemsDownloaded(activities: [Activity])
}

class HomeModel: NSObject
{
    var delegate:HomeModelDelegate?

    func getItems()
    {

        let serviceUrl = "https://www.zzzway.com/dbusers.php"

        let url = URL (string: serviceUrl)

        if let url = url
        {
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)

            let task = session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
                if error == nil
                {
                    self.parseJson(data!)
                }
                else
                {

                }

            })

            task.resume()
        }

    }

    func parseJson(_ data:Data)
    {

        var actArray = [Activity]()

        do {
            let jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [Any]

            for jsonResult in jsonArray

            {

                let jsonDict = jsonResult as! [String:String]

                let act = Activity (NumUser: jsonDict["NumUser"]!, cFirstname: jsonDict["cFirstname"]!, cLastname: jsonDict["cLastname"]!, cEmail: jsonDict["cEmail"]!, cPassword: jsonDict["cPassword"]!, NumPts: jsonDict["NumPts"]!, forgotpass: jsonDict["forgotpass"]!)

                print (act)

                actArray.append(act)

            }

            delegate?.itemsDownloaded(activities: actArray)
           }
        catch
           {
        print("There was an error")
           }

}
}
```

Comment: Is this a repost of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58599704/value-of-type-activity-has-no-member-contains using a different account?

Comment: It's my partner. He wrote an undetailled question so I resposted it here more clear.. hopefully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reflection (coupled with String's .contains method if you are checking String properties) to iterate through your instance variable's properties, and determine whether one of them contains a certain string value.  You can also just create a function that accesses each relevant (String type?) property of your struct/class to check for the string value.

If you post the code definition for Activity we could help you more specifically.

Here's a basic example (without reflection):

```
import Foundation

struct Activity {

    let numUser: Int

    let cFirstName: String

    let cLastName: String

    let cEmail: String

    let cPassword: String

    let numPts: Int

    let forgotPass: Bool

    func activityContainsString(value: String) -> Bool {
        if cFirstName.contains(value) {return true}
        if cLastName.contains(value) {return true}
        if cEmail.contains(value) {return true}
        if cPassword.contains(value) {return true}

        return false
    }
}

let act = Activity(numUser: 5, cFirstName: "John", cLastName: "Doe", cEmail: "john@doe.com", cPassword: "password", numPts: 99, forgotPass: false)

print(act.activityContainsString(value: "magic")) // prints false
print(act.activityContainsString(value: "pass")) // prints true
```

The .contains is a method of String, which can be used in my example by importing Foundation.  If you mean that your actual Activity class does not have a .contains method, that is correct.  It does not.  You have to create your own because the functionality you seem to want is more complex than the simple check that .contains does on a String. The function activityContainsString is an attempt at creating that functionality, iterating through each String property in your class definition and checking whether at least one of these properties contains the string you supply as an argument, and returning true or false as appropriate.

You can even rename the function to **contains** if you want, making it superficially similar to String's method, and you can invoke it in a similar way (make sure the function is inside your Activity definition):

```
func contains(_ value: String) -> Bool {
    if cFirstName.contains(value) {return true}
    if cLastName.contains(value) {return true}
    if cEmail.contains(value) {return true}
    if cPassword.contains(value) {return true}

    return false
}

let act = Activity(numUser: 5, cFirstName: "John", cLastName: "Doe", cEmail: "john@doe.com", cPassword: "password", numPts: 99, forgotPass: false)

print(act.contains("magic")) // prints false
print(act.contains("pass")) // prints true
```